# Transferring touches from uiview to uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I setup my views like this,

```
+- MyView : UIView --------------------+
| A                                    |
|   +- MyTableView : UITableView -----+|
|   |                                 ||
|   |  B                              ||
|   |                                 ||
|   +---------------------------------+|
+--------------------------------------+
```

I want to achieve following two points.

1. Initially, when user starts scrolling MyTableView I don't want to scroll MyTableView (B in the figure) instead I want to move MyView ( A in the figure) at certain point.
2. After reaching a certain point I want start MyTableView scrolling. At this point table should get touch events and super view should NOT. I want this to happen without lifting the touch.

I'm able to achieve 1st part by following code each view's subclass

```
-(BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if  ( _canReceiveTouches )
        return YES;
    return NO;
}
```

Where I enable/disable **_canReceiveTouches**, but I'm not able to achieve 2nd part **without lifting the touch.** I have to lift the touch to table view getting next touch event.

Can some one give me some pointers how to achieve this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `touchesMoved:WithEvent:`

Inside the method, get the location (CGPoint) of the touch using:

```
CGPoint touchLocation = [touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
```

Then compare with the tableview's "top" y (aka origin.y). You can get this using:

CGFloat tableViewOriginY = CGRectGetMinY(self.tableview.frame);

Have a conditional statement checking if "touchLocation.y" is higher or equal than "tableViewOriginY", then you have reached the desired point and you can have your tableview scrolling.

Comment: hi @joakim, Thanks for quick reply. I already have a logic in place that you've just asked me to implement. The only problem here is that I'm not able to get this effect "without lifting finger".  I had to lift my finger to for table view to touch process event.

Comment: Instead of "canReceiveTouches" you could try using the same logic with "scrollEnabled" then. Or a combination of the two.